# Use jquery lazy load plugin with ZURB foundation data-interchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, jquery-lazyload

Im working on a project using the ZURB foundation framework and its data-interchange method to provide different images for different screen sizes.

See:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html

and:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Since the lazy load plugin depends on using 'data-original' to define the image path,
zurb foundation interchange uses 'data-interchange'.

The **ZURB foundation interchange** method adresses images like this:

```
<img data-interchange="[/path/to/default.jpg, (default)], [/path/to/bigger-image.jpg, (large)]">
```

**Lazy load** adresses images like this:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="img/example.jpg" width="640" height="480">
```

**Question:**
How can i use 'data-interchange' instead of 'data-original' in lazy load?
respectively: How is it possible to combine the zurb foundation interchange method with the lazy load plugin?

Thanks for your help!

Vin

Comment: I was just trying to figure this out too!  so far no solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found for now is this one:
[Foundation Interchange + Lazy Loading](http://blog.jonathanargentiero.com/?p=335)

Comment: Your link is 404'ing, [link only answers are considered bad practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Mate you can use http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload,
make two changes on the foundation code:

// fundation.js

```
this.$element.attr('src', path).load(function () {
//Replace:
this.$element.attr('data-original', path).load(function () {
//and
this.$element.css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + path + ')' }).trigger(trigger);    
//Replace:
this.$element.attr('data-original', path).load(function () {_this.currentPath = path;}).trigger(trigger);
```

And use interchange normally, with this changes the lazy load will make the magic.